# remove outliers before doing regression

Tags: regression, outliers

I'm having troubles eliminating the outliers out of my data, before running a regression through it.

**data set structure:**

```
| price | livingArea | area | discrete | dummy |
```

**what I'm doing:**

I'm assuming that 60% of the `price` can be explained by the `livingArea`, 20% of it by the `area` and the rest by `dummy` and `discrete`.

After this I'm trying to find and remove the outliers of `priceForLivingArea/livingAreaSqm` and `priceForArea/areaSqm`. For the outlier detection I'm using the `IQR`, `Q1` and `Q3`.

After removing the "outliers" I'm running a `rlm` regression through the data.  Also I customized the regression with following parameters:

`maxit = 100000, method = "MM", psi = psi.huber, acc = 0.000001,test.vec = "resid", k2 = 1.345, scale.est = "proposal 2"`

```
priceForLivingArea <- 0.6 * price
priceForArea <- 0.2 * price
```

In a minimum average case scenario (data), everything works fine but when the data distribution is bad, the result is horrible.

Also I tried to remove the variable `area` from the regression, if `skewness((priceForArea/area)) > 1.5`

but this approach proved itself to be not useful.

**code:**

```
indexesToRemove <- unique(sort(c(getOutliersIndexes(priceForLivingArea/livingArea), getOutliersIndexes(priceForArea/area))))

if (length(indexesToRemove) > 0) {
   data <- data[-indexesToRemove,]
   weights <- weights[-indexesToRemove]
}


getOutliersIndexes <- function(x) {
   x[which(is.infinite(x))] <- 0
   qnt <- quantile(x, probs = c(.25, .75))
   H <- 1.5 * IQR(x)
   return(c(which(x < (qnt[1] - H)), which(x > (qnt[2] + H))))
}
```

**plot:**
[image]

As you can see in the plot, in this case, my approach wasn't really useful.

**questions:**

- (a) is it really justifiable to remove the outliers?
- (b) is there a better way of removing the outliers, than what I'm using now?
- (c) if I'm removing the outliers, is there still the need to use a robust regression method?

**UPDATE - correlation matrix**

```
              price    livingArea       area      discrete      dummy
price      1.0000000  0.4424315848 0.22561863  0.5260871713 0.18492175
livingArea 0.4424316  1.0000000000 0.23964809 -0.0002193865 0.03934906
area       0.2256186  0.2396480895 1.00000000  0.2300601225 0.07928183
discrete   0.5260872 -0.0002193865 0.23006012  1.0000000000 0.22303584
dummy      0.1849217  0.0393490626 0.07928183  0.2230358365 1.00000000
```

**UPDATE - model purpose**

the purpose of my model is prediction.

Comment: Given this kind of data, I would move immediately to a generalised linear model predicting price using a log link and indeed also using log transforms of continuous predictors such as living area. I think you'd find then that outliers are much less of a concern and indeed most data points will seem part of a reasonable pattern. It is also crucial that such a model guarantees that predictions of price will be positive, which is not all guaranteed by your present model.

Comment: Note that criteria such as identifying points more than upper quartile + 1.5 IQR were never intended to identify outliers to be removed, just to flag points that need to be thought about, the "thinking about" certainly including the idea that a variable would be better off transformed.

Comment: In broad terms, a robust regression is usually intended to circumvent the need for a researcher to remove outliers at all; the intended goal is that the robust method should be relatively unaffected by outliers. (There is lots of small print around those broad terms that fills up several monographs and hundreds if not thousands of articles. The main qualification is that what is an outlier circles round and round with what methods will protect against it.)

Comment: It is essentially always a misconception to assume, or even to guess, that explanation can be divided up into separate chunks provided by each predictor. Living area and area are almost certainly correlated, which undermines that idea.

Comment: @NickCox thank you for the fast response. You mean that by using a semi-log generalized linear model, I don't need to search for outliers and remove them? Using this model I've never got a negative prediction.

Comment: @NickCox I also added the correlation matrix to my question, as we can see, `area` and `livingArea` aren't really correlated. 
splitting it up has proved itself to be an error.

Comment: You're lucky if you never got a negative prediction, but I would still regard a linear model without transformations or with implicit identity link as _prima facie_ unsuitable here. "Correlated" without qualification means that the correlation is not zero. Outliers are much discussed in many threads on CV but removing outliers because they are extreme or awkward to handle goes against the vast majority of statistical advice, or so I would assert.

Comment: Furthermore, my argument implies that correlations between untransformed variables are less pertinent to the analysis than correlations between transformed variables (which I guess would be higher). Posting the data would allow further exploration.

Comment: I don't see an explanation of what `discrete` or `dummy` are.

Comment: Just to amplify NickCox's points about outliers, trimming or deleting them throws away potentially valuable information about the behavior of your DV (price). Also, it's important to distinguish between outliers in the *predictors* vs outliers in the *DV*. Dealing with outliers in the predictors using transformations is much more tractable than the latter. Transformations of the DV make any and all model predictions highly vulnerable to *retransformation bias*, the scourge of predictive modeling.

Comment: @DJohnson We agree in spirit on outliers. Much of the point of generalised linear models (recommended strongly in my first comment) is that retransformation bias is corrected for. The prediction is automatically returned on the original scale. You are clearly correct that logarithmic transformation of the response (DV in your terms) needs to be followed by correction for its side-effects, but the use of a logarithmic link function is not exactly equivalent to log transformation of the response followed by standard linear regression.

Comment: @NickCox `discrete` and `dummy` are bundles of other variables. for example `propetyCondition` and `eneryClass` are discrete values and I'm summing them up in order to have a dimension reduction. I'm doing the same for dummy variables.

Comment: when you talk about `generalized linear model`, are talking about `glm` or some other function? also I haven't found the link `prima facie`?
what do you think about using the Friedman's `MARS` function?

Comment: I don't have experience of MARS; from what I hear it does not tackle your most obvious problem, that of using a plausible specification. See (e.g.) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prima_facie Generalized linear models in R I do gather as being supported by `glm()` but I regret that I can't answer detailed questions about R code, which are off-topic here in any case.

Comment: @Paul, yes MARS is perfect for this type of data, as it is more flexible than GLM as it can handle nonlinear and interaction effects at ease. MARS article has in fact an application of similar dataset as yours.

Comment: @forecaster I used a raw MARS function on my data, but the result wasn't really good. what do you suggest, should I try to remove possible outliers or should I use the raw data and parametrizize the function?

Comment: MARS is immune to outliers, i would run model with and without outliers and see if it improves fit.

Comment: maybe I'm doing something wrong, because I'm getting a really bad result for this data set. the result is worse than the result computed by the `least squares regression`.

Comment: As said I can't advise on MARS but you should ask a new question on that: it will be normally be difficult at best even for MARS experts to comment on "wasn't really good" or "a really bad result". There are no details there on exactly what you did or what went wrong from your point of view. More generally, if you are unable or unwilling to post the data, then naturally we respect that, but by the same token it is difficult to give further advice.

Comment: @NickCox I'll ask then a new question. I'll post also a part of the data, because all of it has > 300 obs. Thank  you for your help.

Comment: I see no problem in posting ~300 observations here.